# How to kill process (created by run-process)

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I want to kill a process started by `(sb-ext:run-program)`.

```
(let ((process (sb-ext:run-program "/path/to/process.sh" '() :wait nil)))
  (sleep 10)
  (sb-ext:process-close process)
  (sb-ext:process-kill process 9 :pid))
```

According to [SBCL-Manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Running-external-programs) `(sb-ext:process-kill process 9 :pid)` should send `SIGKILL` [(which has value 9)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man7/signal.7.html) to `process`, therefore annihilating this process.

But when I am trying to use this using a dummy process:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
while [ $i -lt 4 ]
do
sleep 5
i+=1
done
```

It leaves a corps behind which cannot even be killed using htop + kill.

The process tree before execution looked like this:

```
|- /usr/bin/emacs
| |- /usr/local/bin/sbcl
| | |- /usr/local/bin/sbcl
| | |- /usr/local/bin/sbcl
| | |- /usr/local/bin/sbcl
| | |- /usr/local/bin/sbcl
| | |- /usr/local/bin/sbcl
```

During execution:

```
|- /usr/bin/emacs
| |- /usr/local/bin/sbcl
| | |- /bin/bash /path/to/process.sh
| | | |- sleep 5
| | |- /usr/local/bin/sbcl
| | |- /usr/local/bin/sbcl
| | |- /usr/local/bin/sbcl
| | |- /usr/local/bin/sbcl
| | |- /usr/local/bin/sbcl
```

After execution (the process.sh will not terminate unless the main sbcl is killed/stopped):

```
|- /usr/bin/emacs
| |- /usr/local/bin/sbcl
| | |- process.sh
| | |- /usr/local/bin/sbcl
| | |- /usr/local/bin/sbcl
| | |- /usr/local/bin/sbcl
| | |- /usr/local/bin/sbcl
| | |- /usr/local/bin/sbcl
```

The script can be killed and terminated just fine when started manually and using either `Ctr-C` or `htop + kill`.

**Therefore how can I achive a seamless/corpsless kill within sbcl?**

The same happens when using:

```
(let ((process (sb-ext:run-program "/usr/local/bin/sbcl" '("--dynamic-space-size" "512" "--eval" "(sleep 100)") :wait nil)))
  (sleep 10)
  (sb-ext:process-close process)
  (sb-ext:process-kill process 9 :pid))
```

Comment: If you want an application to terminate you send `SIGTERM` (15). With `SIGKILL` the application doesn't get to cleanup since it never gets the signal. `SIGKILL` is handled by the OS so it's something to use as a last resort before uninstalling or fixing that application before using it again.

Comment: @Sylwester I tried `SIGTERM` (15) before with the same result. Figured if `SIGTERM` isn't doing the deal `SIGKILL` should. Though thank you for the general best concept remark.

Comment: When I remove `(sb-ext:process-close process)` and change signal to `15` it works for me. I'm not sure what `sb-ext:process-close` supposed to do.

Comment: @Sylwester I can confirm - this is quite weird as the description of process-close reads as follows `This function closes all the streams associated with process. When you are done using a process, call this to reclaim system resources.`. But if you add `process-wait` after the kill and an `process-exit-code` after the process-close it also works. Have to use process-close as in my real program I am using streams associated with the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution looks either like this (if you use streams associated with the process you need process-close):

```
(let ((process (sb-ext:run-program "/home/user/processTest.sh" '() :wait nil)))
  (sleep 10)
  (sb-ext:process-kill process 15 :pid)
  (sb-ext:process-wait process)
  (sb-ext:process-close process)
  (sb-ext:process-exit-code process))
```

Or as Sylvester pointed out you can just leave out the `process-close` (if you do not have any streams associated with the process):

```
(let ((process (sb-ext:run-program "/home/user/processTest.sh" '() :wait nil)))
  (sleep 10)
  (sb-ext:process-kill process 15 :pid))
```

`process-close` affects the process in a way that it will become a [zombie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process).

> This occurs for child processes, where the entry is still needed to allow the parent process to read its child's exit status.

As soon as the exit status is read via `process-exit-code` the process is reaped and will disappear.

Comment: There does not seem to be an equivalent implemented in Windows; process-close does work on the stream but the process remains with a status of :running. SBCL does not implement process-kill for Windows.
One alternative is to use "cmd /c taskkill /f /pid" followed by the windows PID of your process.  That PID can be obtained by using (sb-alien:define-alien-routine ("GetProcessId" get-process-id) sb-win32:dword
  (handle sb-win32:handle)) and then calling (get-process-id (sb-ext:process-pid <your-process-here>)).  Thanks to |3b| from #lisp on irc.freenode.net for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the portable `uiop:run-program` instead of the sbcl's one, you can kill the PID by calling run-program a second time, giving it the kill command, just like you would in the shell:

```
(uiop:run-program (format nil "kill ~a" (process-info-pid process)))
```

Where `process` is the return result of the initial `run-program`, the one that started the process you want to kill.